# hex encoded string starting with 0x01000000

Tags: character-encoding, hex

I have a legacy app that stores values in DB as:

0x010000004C41668D6C5C30B39BB81AB3757E7FD75121F6446802D6120A11103C3C563633C6758A110500AC9635DB46B4363CF5FDEC6BC82FB0237412

This looks like a hex encoded string but when I tried to decode it into utf8 or something, it didn't work... Does anybody know what encoding starts with 0x01000000? And how to decode it?

Please, note that this is an Arabic word.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I tried http://linux.die.net/man/1/file file on different parts of your sequence, no part of it was considered text. Binary data was the only response I got. I.e. it is not likely a regular text format.

Comment: You might be correct, I have been testing with different encodings.. and  nothing works...

Comment: Hello! I have the very same question now. Dit you succed in decoding?

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be Unicode text compressed with [SCSU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Compression_Scheme_for_Unicode) or [BOCU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Ordered_Compression_for_Unicode).

Comment: I tried a free SCSU implementation online and it failed to decompress it... and I really doubt it is BOCU...
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hello! I have the very same question now. Dit you succed in decoding?

Comment: Unfortunately not!